# Theming with Views generates error undefined variable

Tags: views

I have a basic installation of Drupal 7, with the Views module. I am using the Garland Template.

When I try to create a new template for my views the following error is thrown:

> Notice: Undefined variable: build in include() (line 2 of /XXX/public_html/themes/garland/views-view—block.tpl.php).

There is only one line in that template:

```
<?php dpm($fields); ?>
```

Most likely this is something simple to resolve, but I cannot find the answer.

Comment: Can you post what is line 2 of /XXX/public_html/themes/garland/views-view--block.tpl.php ?

Comment: <?php dpm($fields); ?>  and devel is installed

Comment: I'm a bit confused.  Is `<?php dpm($fields); ?>` line one or two of your template?  Is the PHP comment listed above part of views-view--block.tpl.php? Also, are you certain that that the template you've quoted is views-view--block.tpl.php and not views-view-block.tpl.php (single dash) or from a Garland subtheme not found at `/XXX/public_html/themes/garland/`?

Comment: I moved to another theme and the issue is gone. Marinelli is the theme I currently use.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what the variable $fields are but try and do a dpm($rows) this should return an array of the fields from the views.

Answer (score 0):

It is because no `$fields` variable is being passed to the template. First check before you do dpm to see if $fields exist and it is not empty.

```
<?php if (!empty($fields)): ?>
    <?php dpm($fields); ?>
<?php endif; ?>
```